# interface builder Storyboard compiler error when build xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I update my xcode to version 8.2.1
and when i build product on xcode the below error occurred:

[image: error]

and my main storyboard like this:

[![storyboard][2]][2]

i search many time but not found any correct solution for this error

anyone can help me?

Edit1:
when i create new project on xcode this error occurred :

> Ld /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test3-brvuxcfxdgdryzefaivvhtzorpiy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test3.app/test3 normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/****/Desktop/test3
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.2
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -L/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test3-brvuxcfxdgdryzefaivvhtzorpiy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test3-brvuxcfxdgdryzefaivvhtzorpiy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test3-brvuxcfxdgdryzefaivvhtzorpiy/Build/Intermediates/test3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test3.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=10.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test3-brvuxcfxdgdryzefaivvhtzorpiy/Build/Intermediates/test3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test3_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test3-brvuxcfxdgdryzefaivvhtzorpiy/Build/Intermediates/test3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test3.swiftmodule -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test3-brvuxcfxdgdryzefaivvhtzorpiy/Build/Intermediates/test3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test3.build/test3.app.xcent -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test3-brvuxcfxdgdryzefaivvhtzorpiy/Build/Intermediates/test3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test3_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test3-brvuxcfxdgdryzefaivvhtzorpiy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test3.app/test3
>
> ld: framework not found Foundation
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: new project error]

Comment: Command + Shift + K or  Command + k to clean.

Comment: command + shift + K clean project and clean succeeded but after that i press command + b that error occure again

Comment: Please insert errors as text and (if necessary) images directly and not as links.

Comment: try to delete derived data in xCode library folder, clean after this and try build again.

Comment: I do this action but it not working @Axel

Comment: Probably xCode generated code doesn't work. what I would do:
1. copy source code of storyboard and paste it in new file.
2. revert project to last working commit. 
3. open source code of reverted storyboard and check what part of generated code doesn't work.

Comment: i revet to last commit but project not working and this error occurred again @Axel

Comment: i update question, please considered again @Axel

Comment: I update question, please considered again @AliBeadle

Comment: I update question, please considered again @Mr.Bista

Comment: When you created a new project was it empty or did you pull in all your old code?

Comment: when it empty second error occurred @AliBeadle

Comment: this error: ld: framework not found Foundation clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) @AliBeadle

Comment: Maybe system default Frameworks aren't imported automatically? Did you try to add `Foundation` framework to your project?

Comment: So your version of XCode is failing to compile a new empty project? Sounds like XCode is corrupted - try downloading and installing again.

Comment: no foundation imported, i create empty project and don't need to Foundation framework   @christian

Comment: If so, I believe you need to re-install xCode as @AliBeadle suggested.

Comment: i remove this xcode and wait to install again, take 55 minute time :|| @christian

Comment: Although note that even a new (Storyboard based iOS) 'empty' app *does* need Foundation - the clue is in the name, it is the foundation of all iOS and OSX APIs. If your XCode is corrupted it could be the absence of the Foundation that is the problem. A reinstall still sounds like the right thing to try.

Comment: Dear friends, i remove xcode and install that after download so every things be alright. i can open previous project and create new project. thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remove xcode
Install again from app store and every things be allright

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by following the below steps in Xcode 8.3.3,

1. Quit Xcode
2. Clear derived data folder of Xcode
3. Relaunch Xcode
4. Clean and run the project again